# ASP.NET MVC 3 - Automatically created MDF file

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, connection-string

I created an ASP.NET MVC 3 project using the default template, when I ran it and created an account, it automatically created an MDF file in my App_Data directory.

The problem is my development machine had a community preview of SQL Server 'Denali' installed, and the application needs to run on SQL Server 2008 R2 - so I can't attach the MDF file to the production instance.

I've changed the MDF file to be a SQL Server 2008 R2 database, attached it to a local instance, and added this to my web.config file (no connection strings were present before this):

```
<add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Data Source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

But my application still seems to look for the older instance, when I try to login now, I get this error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

**My question is** - when Visual Studio 2010 automatically creates an MDF file for you, is there a connection string specified somewhere other than the web.config file?

I've searched through the code and can't seem to find one. I've verified I can connect to the SQL Server 2008 R2 database from other applications.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Is SQL Server 2008 R2 you are running installed as the default instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue in my Web.config file. It's fixed now.